# JMeter java.io.FileNotFoundException in Graphs Generator Listener

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to generate graphs using Graphs Generator Listener for load testing my web application. However, I am getting following error and the graph file does not generate.

```
Error encountered during shutdown of kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener@6d275697
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Software\Network Tools\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\results\ResponseTimesOverTime.png (Access is denied)
```

N.B: The CSV file generating successfully in that folder.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying it cannot write to `F:\Software\Network Tools\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\results\`, either modify the permissions on that directory so it can, or change the location of the output to something you do have permission to write to:

[image]

Comment: In that folder .csv file can write. So .png file why not

Comment: Do you have ResponseTimesOverTime.png open in another program? If so, it could cause the same issue.

Comment: @karim_fci Did you figure this out?

Comment: does not figure out yet. I also not able to save the image in any folder. I am using windows 10.